# Why .bin/www is consider as a javascript file without the .js extention when I use express-generator

Tags: javascript, express

Why is .bin/www considered a javascript file without the .js extention when I use express-generator?

Every time I create a folder bin/ with a www file inside, it's not considered a JavaScript file (which is normal because the .js extention is missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the file is marked "executable" by express-generator:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 samihult  staff  1591 Dec 31 16:07 www
```

Secondly, it starts with a "hashbang" line, which tells what interpreter to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: I don't know if I should create a new post or not but. What is the purpose of putting a hashbang + marked the file as "executable" instead of just creating a .js file ?

Comment: They are just ways of marking the file executable (and telling how it should be executed). You can run `www` directly from the command line. Strictly speaking, it *does not* say that the contents is JavaScript, `.js` extension would imply that more; but it's customary to not have (file format) extensions in executables.

Comment: Putting .js will tell you how it should be executed too (using node or your browser) and it still can be run directly from the command line. So what a .js extension would imply ?

Comment: These are all just conventions, nothing more, and some of them are overlapping. `node` command does not care about the extension, nor does it care if the file is executable or has hashbang or not - it assumes javascript contents. A browser, on the other hand, is more interested about the mime-type of the file, but can use the extension to determine its type as well. A script will be loaded using e.g. `script` tag, and in that case, also the script tag attributes will play role (browsers don't like hashbang lines, they are for command line shells).

Comment: In short: `.js` extension hints you, your editor and your browser what the file type is, but there are plenty of other factors and strategies that are used to determine file type in addition.